# Installing NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have Windows Vista and am running Python 2.7. I am having trouble installing some Python libraries including, NumPy, SciPy, and pygame. I am currently trying to copy the NumPy file straight to my computer (`C:\numpy`) and then unziping the file there. In a command prompt I then run the code;

```
cd c:\numpy
python setup.py config
python setup.py install
```

When I get to the "python setup.py config" part, the command prompt says "this is the wrong setup.py file to run"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the numpy Windows Installer? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy

Answer (score 7):

This is the ANSWER for installing numpy on Windows 8 64 bit.

All you need is:

1.Python, installed in your system, in my case its c:\Python27, its 2.7 version.

2.Install pip if not available.

3. download "numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl" file for 64 bit, you can find this here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

if you don't find it there use mine at: https://github.com/pawanputtaswamy/Libs

How to install:

1.open command prompt (Windows + r and type cmd)

2.Go to pip directory, in my case (cd c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe)

3.Run the following command: pip.exe install \numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

Done

Comment: https://gehrcke.de/2015/02/how-to-set-up-a-64-bit-version-of-numpy-on-windows/ is an expanded version of this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Numpy, Scypy and pygame all have windows installers;  You are advised to use these installers in favor of archive versions.  Make sure you match the version (3.2, 2.7) and archetecture (i386 or x86_64) as the python binary you have installed.

Comment: Thank you, I had never heard of this and realy like the sound of it. I tried the above link and am 99% sure I got the right one, but when I try to import numpy in the python shell it still says "ImportError: No module named numpy"

Comment: Check that you get this one : numpy-1.6.1.win32-py2.7.exe (md5) because you must have the one for your python version 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, depending on your time constraints and situation you could use Enthought's prepackaged python distribution for Windows. The free version:
http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php
has everything you need except pygame which you should be able to install with easy_install once everything else is in place.

Comment: Amazing! It finaly worked! Thank you! I strongly suggest this to anyone else seeking to do anything python!

Answer (score 2):

Open the Python shell and input as such:

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(["install","numpy"])
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact,the method of installing numpy is very easy and quick.First,make sure that Python has already been installed.Then,download the numpy module on sites,such  as
http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/, which provides the numpy module for python2.6.
Finally,double click the module,the rest you have to do is just let it go on.and,it will be installed naturally.

Comment: When I get into the module what do I run, It just lets me see all of numpy's files.

Answer (score 0):

Just go here http://continuum.io/downloads and download the graphical installer.
It will install Numpy, Scipy and a tonne of other useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is a screenshot that can help, Note that I use Ubuntu as operating System

[image]