# Installing numpy on Windows 7 and python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I can't install a library, or at least `numpy`.  I have a Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bits and `Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:18:40) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`.
I go to their [website](http://www.numpy.org/) to *Getting Numpy* which sends me to SourceForge where I download the latest (I have already update my python to 3.3) and open and install it. Apparently successfully. But when I open python and type `import numpy` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
```

The last line it means that %1 it is not a valid Win32 program.

Tere is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7562834/2886003) where they point the OP to the [Windows Installer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy).  So I download the zip file and decompress it. And now?

Somewhere I found that it should be in the Lib folder and then run the setup.py file. I tried again to `import numpy` but again the same error.

I found [here](http://www.andrewsturges.com/2012/05/installing-numpy-for-python-3-in.html) some instructions, but the first step it is already different, my error message it is not the same, is the same as step 6. But then the step 8 is to install the 32-bits system after uninstalling `numpy`and `Python`, but [there is](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.3/) no 32 version for Python 3.3 (or at least not that I understand). What should I do?

So I reinstall the python 3.3 I already had.
And this time when I type `from numpy import *` or `import numpy` I don't get an error but when I try to make an array I do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    type(array([1,6,3,7]))
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

Another way I found is from this [source](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) with python 3.3 which leads me to another unofficial page where I download the *numpy-MKL-1.8.0.win32-py3.3* file following the steps of the blog. But still the same error of NameError.

I didn't restart the computer yet...
I forgot something else or I miss one step?

Comment: So just to clarify - if you write `from numpy import *` followed by `x = array([1,2,3])`, you get a `NameError`, and no other errors?

Comment: True, but now after rebooting it works fine, I will post it as an answer what I consider it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after rebooting it seems to work well. I post here what worked for me

Install python for just for me. Download  from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) the library, install the latest (or the version you want) with 32 bites even if the computer is 64 bites and restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Christophe Gohlke maitains an extensive collection of windows binaries for various python libraries including numpy. Have you tried here?

[/www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: This is the final link I posted it worked well but just after restarting the computer

Comment: Using the binaries in the link it is not necessary to use the 32 bit version of python (they have binaries for both versions).